# select links via voice dictation

Tags: macos, google-chrome, voice, dictation

I've been having some RSI issues, and I'm attempting to use voice controls as much as possible to help my body. I've gotten pretty good as navigating my system and entering text on macos, but web browsing is still a half won battle. I can create new tabs, search for text, and things like that. The missing link though is the ability to select and click links via voice in Chrome. Is this possible to do? Thanks!